# Union with Dates

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, format

I have two tables in BigQuery with the following Fields:
Eventdate.LoadDate.

In table1, the format(STRING) of the date is like this:

```
2023-07-07 06:31:01.623000000
```

In table2, the format(DATETIME) is like this:

```
2022-02-02T07:59:15
```

I need a way to cast the fields so both of them would be DATETIME in this format: “YYYY-MM-DD” the idea is to make a view (the union of both tables) in which the user can search for information like this:

```
SELECT distinct city
FROM VIEW
WHERE Event_date = '2023-07-07'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just simply use `LEFT('' || Event_date, 10)` - this will work for both STRING and DATETIME columns